# Breaking out Case When Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to break out the Select statement to run three difference tables for each investment code?  For example, have all of the True Fixed amounts on one table and all the myga fixed amounts on a separate table?

Comment: Check out `COALESCE()`, to simplify your `case` _expressions_.

Comment: No need to do ´select distinct` combined with `group by`, because your `group by` returns no duplicates.

Comment: ‍Your Code doesn't seems to be working. What you finally need ?

Comment: What are the fields: `IND_FundValue, INT_FundValue, RACT1_FundValue` Yo cannot get them from the way you write the query.